# auto set permission on any file copied into folder

Tags: windows-server-2008, permissions, batch-file

I have a batch file that copies folder from a temp directory to a public internet directory.  The problem is, once the file is copied, the IUSR account doesn't have read privileges to the file and I get a 500 error.  I can manually set permissions after upload, but is there an automatic way to do this for any file that gets added to the folder?

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has a paper called [How permissions are handled when you copy and move files and folders](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310316) that you should find interesting.

An easy answer is to use xcopy.exe, instead of copy.  Using (at least) the following command line option, the file ACL's will remain intact:

```
xcopy.exe source destination /O
```

Answer (score 0):

Got it solved.  I added IUSR permissions to the windows/temp directory and it is inheriting the right permissions now.

Comment: For completeness, the above can be achieved programatically using ICACLS.EXE.